# perl substr remove everything between two positions in string

Tags: perl, indexing, substr

So i have this file clip.txt that only contain:

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanye_West">Kanye West</a>, 
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Martin">Chris Martin</a>
```

Now i would like to remove everything between <...> so that i end up with

Kanye West , Christ Martin.

with perl i have the current code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

$file = 'clip.txt';
open(FILE, $file);
@lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);
$line =  @lines[0];

while (index($line, "<") != -1) {
my $from = rindex($line, "<");
my $to = rindex($line, ">");

print $from;
print ' - ';
print $to;
print ' ';

print substr($line, $from, $to+1);
print '|'; // to see where the line stops
print "\n";
substr($line, $from, $to+1) = ""; //removes between lines
$counter += 1;

}

print $line;
```

all the "print" lines are rather redundant but good for debugging.

now the result becomes:

```
138 - 141 </a>
|
67 - 125 <a href="http://http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Martin">Chris Martin|
61 - 64 </a>, |
0 - 50 <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanye_West">|
Kanye West
```

First the script find position between 138 -141, and removes it.
Then it finds 67 - 125 but it removes 67 - 137.
Next it finds 61 - 64 but it removes 61 - 66.

Why does it do this?
On the bottom line it finds 0 - 64, and it removes perfectly. So i cannot find the logic here.

Comment: One soulution might be to use html parser for perl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`substr`'s third parameter is length, not ending index, so you should pass `$to-$from+1`.

(Though you should also adjust your code to make sure it finds both a `<` and a `>`, and that the `>` is after the `<`.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `s///` operator:

```
$line =~ s/<[^>]+>//g
```

Comment: or the non-greedy? `$line =~ s/<.*?>//g'` :) :)

Answer (score 3):

The proper solution is indeed to use something like [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser%3a%3aSimple). However, if you are just doing this as a learning exercise, you can simplify it by *extracting* what you want rather than removing what you don't:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my $x = index $line, '>';
    next unless ++$x;
    my $y = index $line, '<', $x;
    next unless $y >= 0;
    say substr($line, $x, $y - $x);
}

__DATA__
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanye_West">Kanye West</a>,
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Martin">Chris Martin</a>
```

Output:

```
Kanye West
Chris Martin
```

On the other hand, using an HTML parser isn't really that complicated:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(\*DATA);

while (my $anchor = $parser->get_tag('a')) {
    my $text = $parser->get_text('/a');
    say $text;
}

__DATA__
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanye_West">Kanye West</a>,
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Martin">Chris Martin</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

While a simple regex substitution should do what you want on the example data, [parsing (X)HTML with regexes is generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1184510) (and doing the same thing with a simple character search is basically the same). A more flexible and better readable approach would be to use a proper HTML parser.

Example with [Mojo::DOM](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Mojo::DOM;

# slurp data into a parser object
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do { local $/; <DATA> });

# iterate all links
for my $link ($dom->find('a')->each) {

    # print the link text
    say $link->text;
}

__DATA__
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanye_West">Kanye West</a>, 
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Martin">Chris Martin</a>
```

Output:

```
Kanye West
Chris Martin
```